# Is it possible to make mouse's right click button work as the eraser?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

It is annoying to switch between two tools everytime I make a mistake.

Is there a way to use the **right click** to instantly use the eraser?

I'm using Windows 7 64-bits

Comment: you probably could, if we knew what mouse & what OS you're on... but wouldn't it just be simpler to hit 'b' for brush & 'e' for eraser, same as everybody else does?

Comment: Umm.. I'm using a gaming mouse: Logitech g502 Proteus Core.

Comment: Well, it is for them, not for me. Back then I was using the really old paint from the winxp era, and I was using the right click same color as background (like an eraser), which is way more comfortable. The idea here though is to use the eraser instead of a white color.

Comment: On Windows I'm not sure how flexible the driver is, sorry. On Mac I'd use SteerMouse, which can assign button actions per app, but would still be somewhat difficult to set it to hit 'e' at press, then 'b' at release, whilst also being able to react to left mouse for the actual stroke. It's the kind of thing that really needs to be supported at app-level. I have one app [Cubase] which has a controllable right-click action.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you have a G502. You might be able to poke around in Logitech's gaming mouse software and try some rebinding- possibly using some of the mouse's extra buttons and mixing B & E binds with clicking. http://www.logitech.com/assets/51813/3/lgs-guide.pdf this is logitech's guide to their gaming software.